# Problems Calling SOAP Web Service Using PHP

Tags: php, soap

This is my SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:impl="http://impl.user">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <impl:UserSessionDetails soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <in0 xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">requstXml</in0>
     <in1 xsi:type="impl:UserInfo">
        <password xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">pwd</password>
        <userName xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">pwd</userName>
     </in1>
  </impl:UserSessionDetails>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried the following PHP code:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://example.com/services/?WSDL");
$sh_param = array(
    'userName'    =>    'user',
    'Password'    =>    'pwd'
);

$headers = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', false);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));

$requestXML = '<request name= "UserSessionDetails"><UserDetails><user_name>username</user_name><from_date>fromdate</from_date><to_date>to_date</to_date><group></group></UserDetails></request>';

$result = $soapClient->UserSessionDetails(array('in0'=> $requestXML, 'in1'=> $sh_param));

$simple = $result->$simple = $result->UserSessionDetailsResponse;

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($vals);
echo "</pre>"
```

But it returns nothing. Can anybody please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Enable trace option for soap client and use $soapClient->__getLastRequest/__getLastResponse to check if you are getting empty response (server problem) or response with empty xml node (server just returns "empty" response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use raw xml in SoapClient requests. Use objects/arrays or SoapVar instead.

Basic example:

```
<?php

$client = new \SoapClient('http://example.com/services/?WSDL');

// Optionally your service endpoint
$client->__setLocation('http://example.com/services'); 

$userDetails = new stdClass();
$userDetails->user_name = 'username';
$userDetails->from_date = 'fromdate';
$userDetails->to_date = 'to_date';

$in0 = new stdClass();
$in0->UserDetails = $userDetails;

$in1 = new stdClass();
$in1->userName = 'pwd';
$in1->Password = 'pwd';

$request = new stdClass();
$request->in0 = $in0;
$request->in1 = $in1;

$result = $client->UserSessionDetails($request);
```

You can debug you SOAP services with any SOAP client like [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

P.S. 
Have a look at [Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html) and [SoapVar examples](http://php.net/manual/ru/soapvar.soapvar.php)

Comment: Hey ostin, thanks for ur reply. I've tried like this but still i'm getting nothing. is there anything to do with this "<in1 xsi:type="impl:UserInfo">" in my soap request...?

Comment: I can't really help with request without wsdl provided.
But you should get SoapFault or data, not empty response.

Comment: Check service connection with some SOAP gui client like SoapUI

Comment: I've checked it with SOAP UI and it works but in php still it is not working.

Comment: Then you have to use http://php.net/manual/ru/soapclient.getlastrequest.php and http://php.net/manual/ru/soapclient.getlastresponse.php for debug as @greg suggested